# C++ Function "Automatic" Return Value?

Tags: c++

How is this working? In writing this function, I forgot to include a `return` statement:

```
char *getV(const char *var) {
    char *val = nullptr;
    forward_list<formField>::iterator idx;

    formField ffld;
    idx = _fields.begin();
    while (idx != _fields.end()) {
        ffld = *idx;
        if (strcmp(ffld.Name, var) == 0) {
            val = ffld.Val;
            break;
        }
        idx++;
    }
}
```

Here is `formField`:

```
struct formField {
    char    *Name   = nullptr;
    char    *Val    = nullptr;
};
```

Here's how I'm calling the function:

```
int main () {
    form fdata;

    fdata.add("FirstName", "Alan");

    char *fval = fdata.getV("FirstName");
    if (fval != nullptr) cout << fval;
    else cout << "not found";
    cout << "\n";
}
```

I didn't notice the missing `return` until later, after testing the function and writing other code which uses it. The function is supposed to return `*val`...and it does! How?

Comment: The neverending magic of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour. *anything* is allowed by the compiler; what you expect, nothing, a crash, formatting your harddrive. Your code is ill formed, it has no meaning. And no, the compiler is *not* required to give you an error or warning when you engage in UB. It is *your* responsibility to "just not do that".

Comment: ...washing the dishes, placing obscene phone calls to random numbers in Moscow.... OK, interesting. Thanks.

Comment: It works as expected because the compiler puts `val` variable in `RAX` register (assuming standard calling convention in X64). It's just a coincidence. With different compiler it may break horribly.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I understand. It's not something I did intentionally, or intended to leave as-is (unless it turned out to involved some defined behavior I was unaware of).

Comment: @alanlittle Also note that if you compile with full optimizations then it is possible for you to see different effect because the compiler may fully optimize your function to do nothing, because without the return statement it actually does nothing. You would see the runtime error and/or incorrect behaviour then. It is always a good idea to compile with different flags from time to time.

Comment: doing operations with C-Strings in C++ like in C is not recommended.

Comment: @TheTechel Could you point me to something on that? My understanding is that it's a decision between convenience and efficiency, with strings being more convenient (and less touchy) and c-strings being more efficient. Thanks.

Comment: you would just use std::string or references to one. As far as I see, the values of a 'formField' have to be manually allocated (which is bad) if they are not given statically. You could even replace the entire thing with a std::(unordered_)map

Comment: @TheTechel That's a useful construct. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The calling convention of your platform specifies how the function returns the value it wants to be returned to the caller (e.g: saved in a register). Since the register exists, the caller code just takes the value it finds there, possibly garbage, or the actual good value by chance. Either way, your program invokes undefined behaviour, it cannot be trusted any more.

The solution is to turn the compiler warnings on. E.g, on GCC or Clang:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [[stmt.return]](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return) (**emphasis** mine):

> Flowing off the end of a constructor, a destructor, or a function with a cv `void` return type is equivalent to a `return` with no operand.
>   Otherwise, flowing off the end of a function other than `main` results in **undefined behavior**.

Usually you can catch these kinds of errors by turning on and reading warnings generated by the compiler (e.g. by using `-Wall -Wextra` with GCC or Clang).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Yes it does. Undefined behavior can include "returns a value".

Comment: And the OP is asking for a description of how that specific outcome has been achieved in this instance. Personally I usually leave it at the advice "don't ask these questions", but simply repeating the premise of the question isn't answering it.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. "Undefined behavior" is answer enough, and jotik posted first, though erenon's answer is more technically complete. I wish I'd seen the previous questions, but they did not show up in my search.

Comment: @Dayan I suppose not. If it matters to erenon, I'll change it and accept his/her answer.

Comment: @alanlittle You should accept the answer you find most useful. Your vote pins it to the top, so make it count.

Comment: @BaummitAugen They're both informative. While I'm new to C, I understand the idea of `undefined behavior`, so that was sufficient to let me know it's not something I can rely on. I'm just trying to be fair (I'm also new to this forum!)

Comment: @alanlittle *"I'm just trying to be fair"* The main purpose of the accept vote is not to reward the answer's author, although it does that too. It exists because we trust the OP to be able to evaluate the usefulness of the answers quite well, as OP must use them to solve their problem. Hence the big impact on the default answer sorting. So again: Pick the one you personally found most useful. (Not arguing about your choice here, just explaining the general principle.)

Comment: @BaummitAugen Good point. Sorry, jotik!

Comment: @alanlittle No problem! Welcome to Stack Overflow! :-)